# Get custom data in application - Pushwoosh

Tags: cordova, pushwoosh, remoteapi

I have a Premium Account from Pushwoosh and I want to send custom data (JSON) from the server over the Remote API. Now my question is, how do I get this data in my application. So how can I read this data in my Application. I am programming in Android using Phonegap(Cordova)? 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You receive push notifications in Phonegap (Cordova) on Android as a JSON payload. Custom data is contained in this payload. It should be under "userdata" or "u" key.

You can also dump JSON to console or display it as an alert to see its contents (you will need to use JSON.stringify for that).